# Creating average groups by customer

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregate

have a table:

- CUSTOMERID
- START
- END
- AMOUNT

Need to have a result:

- CUSTOMERID
- 30 DAYS AVG AMOUNT
- 15 DAYS AVG AMOUNT
- 5 DAYS AVG AMOUNT

This is my Query:

```
SELECT CUSTOMERID,
    CASE 
        WHEN START_DT > (SYSDATE - 5)
            AND END_DT > (SYSDATE - 5)
            THEN AVG(AMOUNT)
        ELSE 0
        END AS FIVE,
    CASE 
        WHEN (
                START_DT BETWEEN (SYSDATE - 5)
                    AND SYSDATE - 15
                )
            AND (
                END_DT BETWEEN (SYSDATE - 5)
                    AND SYSDATE - 15
                )
            THEN AVG(AMOUNT)
        ELSE 0
        END AS FIFTEEN,
    CASE 
        WHEN (
                START_DT BETWEEN (SYSDATE - 15)
                    AND SYSDATE - 30
                )
            AND (
                END_DT BETWEEN (SYSDATE - 15)
                    AND SYSDATE - 30
                )
            THEN AVG(AMOUNT)
        ELSE 0
        END AS THIRTY
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND START_DT > (SYSDATE - 30)
    AND AMOUNT > 0
GROUP BY CUSTOMERID,
    START_DT,
    END_DT
```

It seems like I am not doing it right, since I am getting too many zeroes, but they should not be there since I filter by AMOUNT>0 ; any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `group by` somewhere along the way.  Something like:

```
SELECT CUSTOMERID,
       AVG(CASE  WHEN START_DT > (SYSDATE - 5) AND END_DT > (SYSDATE - 5)
                 THEN AMOUNT
           END) AS FIVE,
       AVG(CASE WHEN START_DT BETWEEN (SYSDATE - 5) AND SYSDATE - 15 AND
                     END_DT BETWEEN (SYSDATE - 5) AND SYSDATE - 15
                THEN AMOUNT
           END) AS FIFTEEN,
       AVG(CASE WHEN START_DT BETWEEN (SYSDATE - 15) AND SYSDATE - 30 AND
                     END_DT BETWEEN (SYSDATE - 15) AND SYSDATE - 30 
                THEN AMOUNT
           END) AS THIRTY
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE 1 = 1 AND START_DT > (SYSDATE - 30)
GROUP BY CUSTOMERID;
```

Note that the `case` goes inside the `avg()`.  And, there is no `else`clause.  `AVG()` ignores `NULL` values, which is what you want in this case.